# Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray). tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

please help explaining what am I doing wrong here for a complete newbie.
This is my first ever ml code and it is used for object detection. Please tell me my mistakes and how to make them right!

```
from numpy.lib.shape_base import split
from numpy.core.fromnumeric import var
from numpy.core.memmap import ndarray
from tensorflow_datasets.object_detection.voc import Voc
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



voc = tfds.object_detection.voc
(training_images,training_labels) = tfds.as_numpy(tfds.load(
    'voc',
    split=['train','train'],batch_size=-1))
x = dict.items(training_images)
x =list(x)
x = np.array(x)





model = tf.keras.Sequential([   tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(0,0,3)),
                                tf.keras.layers.Dense(18, activation = tf.nn.relu),
                                 tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1) , loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics = ('accuracy'))
model.fit( x ,epochs=100)
```

Here is the full error message:

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-1-fbcca47159b2> in <module> 
41 model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1) , loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
42 metrics = ('accuracy')) 
---> 43 model.fit( x ,epochs=100) 
44 45 
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype) 
100 dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum 
101 ctx.ensure_initialized() 
--> 102 return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype) 
103 104 

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

Comment: When asking debugging questions you need to provide the full error message.

Comment: This is the whole error message. Also I am just asking for help as a newbie man, so can you make it any easier please?

Comment: No, please show the full error stack. This is not enough.

Comment: Okay I just did it. Is that okay?

Comment: I have a lot of questions in re your code. First time I see `batch_size=-1`. Why is the input shape for Flatten layer `(0, 0, 3)`? Finally, fit function expects either `x` and `y` tensors or a single array containing both x and y, like `[x, y]`. Where's your `y`?

Comment: it looks like you are trying to make a simple 4 layer neural network using keras !!

Comment: I used "batch_size = -1" because it was the documentation on how to load the dataset

Comment: And what should I used for the input_shape?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing the images and labels to `model.fit` together, but `fit` expects two separate arguments: one for the images and one for the labels.

Try changing your last line of code to this:

```
model.fit(x[0], training_labels, epochs=100)
```